# PHP How to submit form, if there are no errors. no javascript

Tags: php, html, email

I have separate email script; however, how would we run that code if there are no errors. I have a array with form errors   `$errors = array($nameErr, $emailErr, $phoneErr, $zipErr, $serviceErr);` but they have different strings, if there are no strings or `Null` or `''`  inside the array, we would like to send email.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $zipErr = $serviceErr = "";
$name = $phone = $email = $zip = $service = $comment = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "name required.";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "letters and spaces only."; 
     }
   }
   
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "email required.";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "invalid email format."; 
     }
   }
   
   if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
       $phoneErr = "phone required.";
   } else {
    //Check phone for numbers () or - only
       $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[\+0-9\-\(\)\s]*$/", $phone)) {
     $phoneErr = "format.";     
    }
   }
   
     if (empty($_POST["zip"])) {
       $zipErr = "zip required.";
   } else {
       $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
   }
   if (!preg_match("/^[\+0-9\-\(\)\s]*$/", $zip)){
       $zipErr = "format.";
   }
   
   
   if ($_POST["service"] == NULL ) {
       $serviceErr = "service required.";
   }else {
    $service = test_input($_POST["service"]);
   }
 $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
 
 //**********************************************************************
 $errors = array($nameErr, $emailErr, $phoneErr, $zipErr, $serviceErr); 
 if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            //if no errors run send email CODE.
     }
    //***********************************************************************
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
<form <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> Name:
   <br />
   <input name="name" type="text" size="20" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo "<br />"; echo $nameErr;?></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> Phone:
   <br />
   <input name="phone" type="text"  size="20" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo "<br />"; echo $phoneErr;?></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> E-mail:
   <br />
   <input name="email" type="text" size="20" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo "<br />"; echo $emailErr;?></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> Zip:
   <br />
   <input name="zip" type="text" size="20" value="<?php echo $zip;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo "<br />"; echo $zipErr;?></span>   
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> Service:
   <br />
   <select name="service">
    <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $service;?>"><?php echo $service;?></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">* <?php echo "<br />"; echo $serviceErr;?></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> Message:
   <br />
   <textarea name="comment" rows="2" cols="20"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $phone;
echo "<br>";
echo $zip;
echo "<br>";
echo $service;
echo "<br>";
echo "$comment";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So are you asking how to send an email, or how to do the validation?

Comment: Checking an array of errors from the validation, if no errors run the send email code. @ Ashique C M code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the below code:

```
$errors = array($nameErr, $emailErr, $phoneErr, $zipErr, $serviceErr);  
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
   if(!array_filter($errors)){
           // code here 
   }
   else {
   echo "Error";
   }
}
```

Comment: you can add the code in // code here else condition you may remove or print the error.

Answer (score 0):

Save your errors in an array, then check if the array is empty at the end. If so, no errors - submit email. Else, display errors:

```
//dont declare separate variables,use an array
//$nameErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $zipErr = $serviceErr = "";
$errors = [];

if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $errors['nameErr'] = "name required.";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $errors['nameErr'] = "letters and spaces only."; 
     }
   }

//other validation here, then

if(empty($errors){
    //no errors, submit
    your_submit_function();
}else{
    //display errors
    foreach($errors as $val){
        echo $val . '<br/>';
    }
}
```